# How do I get Thymeleaf to read the value of a radio button?

Tags: spring-boot, radio-button, thymeleaf

I can't seem to get Spring Boot / Thymeleaf to determine if a radio buttons is checked or not.
I am pretty new to Thymeleaf so I assume it's something simple I am missing.

**My "Search DTO"**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Component
public class DateRangeDto {
    private String dateFilter = "";
    private Date fromDate = new Date();
    private Date toDate = new Date();
}
```

**My Controller**

```
private final DateService service;
private final DateRangeDto dateRangeDto;


public DataController(DateService service, DateRangeDto dateRangeDto) {
    this.service = service;
    this.dateRangeDto = dateRangeDto;
}

....

@PostMapping("/date")
public String applyDateRangeFilter(Model model, Pageable pageable) {

    model.addAttribute("dateRangeDto", dateRangeDto);
    model.addAttribute("list", service.findAll(pageable));

    return "/fragments/filter-date";
}
```

**My view template**

```
<input th:type="radio"
    th:field="${dateRangeDto.dateFilter}"
    th:checked="${dateRangeDto.dateFilter == 'pastHour'}"
    th:name="'dateFilter'"
    th:value="'pastHour'"
    id="rbPastHour"/>
```

I have tried many variations and cannot seem to grasp this.  What I expect to happen is that when the "rbPastHour" radio button is checked, its value should be "pastHour" in which the controller/service will alter the search based on that.

However, the controller does not see any value at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not bind your form to something that is a Spring component. Maybe read up on [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) to better understand how things work.

Comment: Every time I look up Thymeleaf your name pops up.  :-)  I will certainly take your advice as you know your stuff.  Thanks!